# How to run script without duplicate

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

So, I came across this very good script of how to send an email (Gmail) using data taken from gsheet.

The problem is, every time a new row is added (a new email address is added), an email will be sent to the new email address and the existing one.

I would like to know how to run a script but still able to skip the existing data.

```
function sendEmail() {

var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
var sheet1=ss.getSheetByName('OMS');
var sheet2=ss.getSheetByName('Email');
var subject = sheet2.getRange(2,1).getValue();;
var message = sheet2.getRange(2,2).getValue();
var n=sheet1.getLastRow();
for (var i = 2; i < n+1 ; i++ ) {
var emailAddress = sheet1.getRange(i,4).getValue();
MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, message);
}

}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: use a column to remember which lines to skip and mark it to skip whenever you send an email from that line or you could just delete the line.

Comment: Hi @cooper, thank you for replying. I could not delete the existing data as it is our internal log. looking for any function that only runs on new data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Modified Script

```js
function sendEmail() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet1 = ss.getSheetByName("OMS");
  var sheet2 = ss.getSheetByName("Email");
  var subject = sheet2.getRange(2, 1).getValue();
  var message = sheet2.getRange(2, 2).getValue();
  var n = sheet1.getLastRow();
  for (var i = 2; i < n + 1; i++) {
 
    if (sheet1.getRange(i, 5).getValue() === "") { // NEW LINE

      var emailAddress = sheet1.getRange(i, 4).getValue();
      MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, message);

      sheet1.getRange(i, 5).setValue("EMAIL SENT") // NEW LINE
    } // NEW LINE
  }
}
```

This will require you to add an extra column (column 5), that this script will now check for an empty value. If the value is not empty, then it will skip this row. If it is empty, then it will add "EMAIL SENT" to column 5.

[`if` statement documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/if...else) if you are interested to learn more about conditional execution.

Comment: Hi @iansedano the modified script actually works! Thanks! Also, can I use the "if" function if let says I want the email to be sent if data are added on a certain date only?

Comment: No problem! Using dates is possible, but dates can get complex depending on what you want to do exactly.

Comment: Hi @iansedano, can I email or speak to you separately on adding the additional function?

Comment: Hi @Zieyra  I think it would be easiest if you asked another question, that way if someone else has this confusion they can look at your question too